# Difference between android.intent.category.LAUNCHER and android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER

Tags: android, android-things

I was going through the sample program of Android things and i have found 2  there.

One was having `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` and another was having `<category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER"/>` , So what is the basic diffence between both of them?

[reference link](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-simpleui/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation states:

> An application intending to run on an embedded device must declare an activity in its manifest as the main entry point **after the device boots**

The Activity declared as `IOT_LAUNCHER` will automatically start, when the device boots.

The definition in `AndroidManifest.xml` must contain the intent filter with 3 elements:

- Action: ACTION_MAIN
- Category: CATEGORY_DEFAULT
- Category: IOT_LAUNCHER

Look [here](https://developer.android.com/things/training/first-device/create-studio-project.html#declare_a_home_activity) for more info.

There is nothing that prevents you from declaring the same activity as a default start `Activity` to be run from Android Studio. The same `Activity` would be run a boot and by a programmer.

Comment: Does it mean whenever i restart my Raspberry-pi or any other board, this activity will run by default?

Comment: Yes it should. Google developers expect that "embedded devices typically present a single app experience to users.(...) The Android Things platform is also streamlined for single application use. System apps are not present, and your app is launched automatically on startup to immerse your users in the app experience." So on system boot one application would be shown to the user.

Comment: _"The Activity declared as IOT_LAUNCHER will automatically start, when the device boots"_, unless, as of `Android Things Developer Preview`, there are more applications with `IOT_LAUNCHER` in manifest, in this case [the system displays an app chooser](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html) (see Known issues)

Answer (score 2):

Please find below difference between `IOT_LAUNCHER` and `LAUNCHER`:

**IOT_LAUNCHER:**

This intent is for Android Things which is an extended Android Framework for Internet Of Things(IOT) which is used for embedded programming using Android.
Please check this [link](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html) for more information.

**LAUNCHER:**

This intent is for normal Android application which is for mobile and Tablet Device.

There is also one more intent action which is, `LEANBACK_LAUNCHER` used for Android TV applications.
Google Play store filters applications using this intent actions only.

Thanks.

Comment: This answer is addressing the question better (although the other answer is technically correct and well explained)

Comment: @shalafi: Thank You!